# Google API C# SDK get profile email

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-people-api

We're integrating Google api C# SDK to our application and following Google "web application" workflow.
We need to retrieve currently authenticated Google user email.

We get it works using one of these approaches:

1. Directly make http request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=xxx .
2. Use Google people api C# sdk

```
    var peopleService = new PeopleServiceService(new BaseClientService.Initializer { HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential, ApplicationName = "Test App" });
    
    var peopleRequest = peopleService.People.Get("people/me");
    peopleRequest.RequestMaskIncludeField = new List<string> { "person.EmailAddresses" };

    var profile = peopleRequest.Execute();
```

3. Use Google Gmail api C# sdk

```
    var gmailService = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer                                                                     
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential, ApplicationName = "Test App"                                                                    
        });

    var gmailProfile = gmailService.Users.GetProfile("me").Execute();
    var userGmailEmail = gmailProfile.EmailAddress;
```

Scopes we're using are:

> *"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly" "email" "profile"*

Examples above work well, however we don't want to use *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly* as it's "restricted" scope.

So, we wonder if there any chance to call the Google profile email using some method from C# SDK ?

Thanks in advance,
Evgeny.

Answer (score 1):

`Profile` [scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#people) will give you access to [google people api](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) however i think you need to user.emails.read to get access to their email address.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.emails.read   View your email addresses

using a gmail scope seems like overkill if you just want the users email address.  Which api are you using in general some of them have ways of getting the users email.

Comment: Hi @DalmTo. Thank you, I've tried scopes ang people.get() method you've advised - and it works well too. However my question was if there some "out of box" method in C# SDK to obtain UserInfo obejct, something like SomeBaseGoogleService.GetUserInfo().Execute(). Is something similar existing ?

Comment: the client library is built around allowing you to access the different apis.  In this case the people API.   So no there are no simple methods which would get you this information.   you need to create a peopleservice an request what ever data you need from that API yourself